# The module "%VSINSTALLDIR%\DIA SDK\bin\msdia140.dll" failed to load, while trying to install llvm on windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio, installation, llvm

I am trying to get started with compiler development using llvm, I follow [official setup page](https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html) on the 10th step and am getting the following error

> The module "%VSINSTALLDIR%\DIA SDK\bin\msdia140.dll" failed to load make sure the binary is stored at specified path or debug it to check for problems with binary or dependent .DLL files. The specified module could not be found.

Visual Studio 2022 information :

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.1.6
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.6+32421.90
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084
Installed Version: Community
Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA606
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.1.363.30963
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.1.363.30963
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0
C# Tools   4.1.0-5.22165.10+e555772db77ca828b02b4bd547c318387f11d01f
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package
NuGet Package Manager   6.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.
Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.
TypeScript Tools   17.0.1229.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
Visual Basic Tools   4.1.0-5.22165.10+e555772db77ca828b02b4bd547c318387f11d01f
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.
Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for CMake
```

I am trying to get llvm up and running, The .dll files are available at the given location, please help.

> $ ls
> amd64/  arm/  arm64/  msdia140.dll*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you at first, please read my solution carefully:

1. You need to use the `cd` command to enter the folder where you want to install LLVM. Regarding the `cd` command, I suggest you search for usage methods on Google, I believe it will be easier to understand than what I described.

> The documentation mentions that You may install the llvm sources in
> other location than c:\llvm but do not install into a path containing
> spaces (e.g. c:\Documents and Settings...) as it will fail.

[image]

2. Run the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 as an administrator.

[image]

3. Enter regsvr32 "%VSINSTALLDIR%\DIA SDK\bin\msdia140.dll" to get the following result.

[image]

**Please look carefully at Figure 1**.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is quite frustrating to get these things up and running, btw now that I have got this solved, it is another thing to actually write an llvm hello world pass, I'm literally overwhelmed and intimidated, where an how to write the first pass, the official llvm page isn't very helpful, do you know how I might do it or point me to some helpful blog or a video that explains it step by step, it would be a great help.